# ADF Convert String into Json object

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a parent pipeline (A) calling child pipeline (B)
by using execute Pipeline activity.
The Pipeline B creates the web request and returns the data in this form

```
"varOutputJSon": [
        "[{\"ID\":12356958,\"ClientId\":56565989,\"ClientName\":\"Client Name\"}]
```

(varOutputJSon is a pipeline return variable)

What i need is something to do with it in the pipeline A, so that I get an object, so that I can get each field separately
Something like

```
varObj.ID - to get ID
 or
varObj.ClientName - to get the Client Name as a field.
```

Would appreciate any help.  My idea is to keep replacing **`'\"'`** with  simple **`'"'`** and then using a @json() fucnction .. but I haven't been able to get it to work.  My result keeps being a string, just without the `'\"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADF, by default "`\`" will be added as an escape character for the '`"`' in the strings when displaying the values.

This won't affect the value of the string and ADF will be the same string. For sample, here I am checking the sample string "`[{"ID":12356958,"ClientId":56565989,"ClientName":"Client Name"}]`" length and storing in an integer variable with below expression.

```
@length('[{"ID":12356958,"ClientId":56565989,"ClientName":"Client Name"}]')
```

You can see the length of the above string is 64.

[image]

Then I have stored the same string in a string variable which will be displayed like this with escape character`/` for the `"`.

[image]

Now, I am storing the length of the above variable `@length(variables('str_var'))` and you can see it is same as above.

[image]

So, it won't take the `\` value in ADF. That is the reason why it is giving the same string when you are trying to replace because there is no `/"` in the string.

To get the JSON array, use `@json()` direclty on the above value and it will give the required result.

**Child Pipeline returned json string:**

[image]

**Parent pipeline:**

```
@json(activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.varOutputJSon)
```

[image]

**Result JSON array** in an array variable:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer !!
It lead me to find solution.  Directly your method did not work, but the issue was that in my child pipeline, I was converting the response to String and so .. your method could not convert string to array,.  Once I fould it and started returning pure array, it worked